# Position a full width logo in scrlttr2 header

Tags: header-footer, scrlttr2

How can I position a fullwidth logo in the top left corner of my `scrlttr2` document? The following code leaves a small but noticable gap.

```
\documentclass[12pt,ngerman]{scrlttr2}
\usepackage{babel}
\setkomavar{fromname}{Just me}

\makeatletter
\@setplength{firstheadhpos}{0mm}
\@setplength{firstheadvpos}{0mm}
\makeatother

\firsthead{
\rule{\paperwidth}{3cm}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{John Doe \\ Berlin}
\opening{Dear John,}

\closing{Mit freundlichen Scherzen,}

\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

[image: scrlttr2]

Comment: See [What is the use of percent signs (`%`) at the end of lines?](http://goo.gl/awJkj)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that

```
\firsthead{
\rule{\paperwidth}{3cm}
}
```

adds horizontal space if you don't avoid it putting a `%` after `\firsthead{`, so you would have to write

```
\firsthead{%
\rule{\paperwidth}{3cm}
}
```

Moreover, the use of `\firsthead` is deprecated. You should use the following syntax instead:

```
\setkomavar{firsthead}{%
\rule{\paperwidth}{3cm}%
}
```

Complete MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt,ngerman]{scrlttr2}
\usepackage{babel}
\setkomavar{fromname}{Just me}

\makeatletter
\@setplength{firstheadhpos}{0mm}
\@setplength{firstheadvpos}{0mm}
\makeatother

\setkomavar{firsthead}{%
\rule{\paperwidth}{3cm}%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{John Doe \\ Berlin}
\opening{Dear John,}

\closing{Mit freundlichen Scherzen,}

\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]